# Ubuntu 18.04: No sound from speaker

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I am using Dell latitude 5490 and after upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04, The speakers are not working. 
I tried to follow some of steps mentioned 
[here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2390774) and [here](https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/) but none of them seem to work.

Here is the out of the command

```
pacmd list-sinks

1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE
    priority: 9039
    volume: front-left: 53577 /  82% / -5.25 dB,   front-right: 53577 /  82% / -5.25 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max request: 0 KiB
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    monitor source: 0
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 371.52 ms
    card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3>
    module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "Generic Analog"
        alsa.id = "Generic Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xef348000 irq 140"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "9d71"
        device.product.name = "Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "front:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek Generic"
        alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0256,10280816,00100002 HDA:8086280b,80860101,00100000"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
    active port: <analog-output-headphones>
```

Here is the screenshot of the output from alsamixer[image]

Answer (score 0):

So found out that the issue was not with ubuntu but with the speakers, I should have run the system diagnostics first and then tried to see if the issue was with the software,

For anyone else who might be experiencing a sound issue,

1. Please run System Diagnostics first (Press `F12` while booting)  and see if you are able to hear the sound from the speaker,
2. If that is not working try to run a `Ubuntu`/any other distro without installing and do a sound test.

If both of these are not working the issue might be with the hardware. If one of them is not working try to see if it is a problem with `pulse audio`, or if your system audio is set to 0 through `alsamixer`.